# Why do I get NAs in my confusionMatrix doing KNN?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, r-caret, knn

Working with R, I performed a KNN Algorithm `knn <- train(x = x_train, y = y_train, method = "knn")` with this dataframe:

```
1   0.35955056  0.62068966  0.34177215  0.27    0.7260274   0.22    MIT
2   0.59550562  0.56321839  0.35443038  0.15    0.7260274   0.22    MIT
3   0.52808989  0.35632184  0.45569620  0.13    0.7397260   0.22    NUC
4   0.34831461  0.35632184  0.34177215  0.54    0.6575342   0.22    MIT
5   0.44943820  0.31034483  0.44303797  0.17    0.6712329   0.22    CYT
6   0.43820225  0.47126437  0.34177215  0.65    0.7260274   0.22    MIT
7   0.41573034  0.36781609  0.48101266  0.20    0.7945205   0.34    NUC
8   0.49438202  0.42528736  0.56962025  0.36    0.6712329   0.22    MIT
9   0.32584270  0.29885057  0.49367089  0.15    0.7945205   0.30    CYT
10  0.35955056  0.29885057  0.41772152  0.21    0.7260274   0.27    NU
...
```

Obtaining this result:

```
k-Nearest Neighbors 

945 samples
  6 predictor
  8 classes: 'CYT', 'ERL', 'EXC', 'ME', 'MIT', 'NUC', 'POX', 'VAC' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Bootstrapped (25 reps) 
Summary of sample sizes: 945, 945, 945, 945, 945, 945, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  k  Accuracy   Kappa    
  5  0.5273630  0.3760233
  7  0.5480598  0.4004283
  9  0.5667651  0.4242597

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final value used for the model was k = 9.
```

After that, I wanted to do a confusion matrix with this code:

```
predictions <- predict(knn, x_test)
results <- data.frame(real = y_test, predicted = predictions)
attach(results)
confusionMatrix(real, predicted)
```

And I got this results:

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction CYT ERL EXC ME MIT NUC POX VAC
       CYT  73   0   0  3   7  44   0   0
       ERL   0   0   0  1   0   0   0   0
       EXC   2   0   6  3   1   0   0   0
       ME    5   0   1 68   2  11   0   0
       MIT  19   0   0  8  44  14   0   0
       NUC  57   0   0  6   8  74   0   0
       POX   3   0   0  0   1   2   0   0
       VAC   3   0   2  2   1   1   0   0

Overall Statistics

               Accuracy : 0.5614          
                 95% CI : (0.5153, 0.6068)
    No Information Rate : 0.3432          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16       

                  Kappa : 0.417           

 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA              

Statistics by Class:

                        Class: CYT Class: ERL Class: EXC Class: ME Class: MIT Class: NUC Class: POX Class: VAC
Sensitivity              0.4506         NA    0.66667    0.7473    0.68750     0.5068         NA         NA
Specificity              0.8258   0.997881    0.98704    0.9501    0.89951     0.7822    0.98729    0.98093
Pos Pred Value           0.5748         NA    0.50000    0.7816    0.51765     0.5103         NA         NA
Neg Pred Value           0.7420         NA    0.99348    0.9403    0.94832     0.7798         NA         NA
Prevalence               0.3432   0.000000    0.01907    0.1928    0.13559     0.3093    0.00000    0.00000
Detection Rate           0.1547   0.000000    0.01271    0.1441    0.09322     0.1568    0.00000    0.00000
Detection Prevalence     0.2691   0.002119    0.02542    0.1843    0.18008     0.3072    0.01271    0.01907
Balanced Accuracy        0.6382         NA    0.82685    0.8487    0.79350     0.6445         NA         NA
```

I would like to know why I have got this NAs in my sensibility in the class ERL for example.

Did I do something wrong ?

What is the reason of these NAs. I can provided the completed dataframe if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the confusion matrix, your prediction set is lacking data with the classification of ERL, POX, and VOC which is leading to the NAs in the Statistics by Class.

Take a look at the Sensitivity of Class ERL for example. Sensitivity, also called the True Positive Rate, is calculated as the number of correct positive predictions divided by the total number of positives.

```
Positive ERL Predictions = 0  
Actual ERL Classifications = 0  
Sensitivity ERL = 0/0 which leads to the NA.
```

Comment: Hello Josiah and welcome to stack overflow.

I already know what you mean, but still I dont know why is NA. Because As fas as I know Positive ERL Predictions and Actual ERL Classifications are not 0 right?

Comment: Based on the confusion matrix, Reference ERL is all 0's, meaning there aren't any ERL classifications in the prediction set (same for POX and VAC). Since there aren't any actual ERL classifications, it's not possible to have a positive ERL prediction. So R is handling the Positive ERL Predictions and Actual ERL Classifications as 0 or NA.  

In R:  
    0/0 = NaN

Comment: Edit to my previous comment (didn't know there was a 5 minute edit window). In R: 0/0 = NaN and 0/NA (or any mathematical relation between a number and NA) results in an NA.